# How to write a shell script to check the service file is running or not if not then restart the service?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have written one shell script to check the status of a service file, if I run that script I'm getting an error.

```
#! /bin/sh
SERVICE = myApp

while(true)
do
   if ! ps -ef | grep -i $SERVICE > /dev/null
       then nohup /full_path/runMyApp & 
   fi
   sleep 10
done
```

here I'm getting error as follows:

> try grep [OPTION]... pattern[FILE]... nohup:failed to run command 'full_path/runMyApp':no such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? And are you working with `/full_path` (absolute directory) or `full_path` (relative to script location)?

Comment: Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance. You have multiple common beginner syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grep command fails, and myApp isn't found in the path you give.

Problems/fixes in your script:

1. Don't put a space between `#!` and `/bin/sh`.
2. You **must not** have spaces around the `=` sign when you assign a variable (this causes your `grep` to fail).
3. The variable should be quoted in the `grep` command, in case the name has a space.
4. Make sure there is a `/` before *and* after the path to `myApp`. It looks like you might have missed the trailing `/` above.
5. When grepping for a process (not the best way to check if a process is running), make sure you exclude the `grep` process itself, otherwise you'll always see some process running and think your service is up.
6. The parenthesis in `while` isn't needed, as this isn't C. In `sh`, it means you run the command `true` in a subshell.
7. `grep` has a parameter `-q` which makes it output nothing. This is better than redirecting to `/dev/null`.

Putting it all together:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE="myApp"

while true
do
   if ! ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -qi "$SERVICE"
       then nohup "/full_path/$SERVICE" & 
   fi
   sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Dear Sir, I have changed my shell script like this:

Comment: instead of grep I used pgrep: if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null and this is working fine, Thanks for your Support sir